# Removing different words form a document using R console

Tags: r, information-retrieval

I have managed to retrieve a text file but i want to remove different words. I have gone to read.table and have no clue how to use it to help me remove certain words. I have got 300 words and these are some of them. How can remove all these words using the R console? I have two files, one is sk.text which is a whole document and the other one is bash.txt that has got just words, so i want to remove all the words in sk.text that match the words given in bash.text.

```
 with
 within
 without
 work
 worked
 working
 works
 would
```

Comment: So you want to read a file in, remove certain words, and write a file out?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Yeah, i have two files, one is sk.text which is a whole document and the other one is bash.txt that has got just words, so i want to remove all the words in sk.text that match the words given in bash.text.

Comment: Please edit the question. Do not put extra info in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to use

```
gsub(paste0('\\b',
            YOURVECTOROFWORDSTOREMOVE,
            '\\b', collapse = '|'),'',YOURSTRING)
```

which replaces every occurence of the words in the vector surrounded by either end/beginning characters or whitespace with a single space.

but you might want to look at the tm package and work with a corpus object if you have many files like this. there you can remove the words you like simply with

```
tm_map(YOURCORPUS, removeWords, YOURVECTOROFWORDSTOREMOVE)
```

Comment: Try instead `gsub(paste0('\\b', x, '\\b', collapse="|"), '', YOURSTRING)`

Comment: Whoo didn't know about \b. Sweet-